# Apache 2.4 Being a Complete Jerk and Not Allowing non-localhost Traffic Under Any Circumstances

Tags: apache

I'm super frustrated and created an account just to get this solved. I've tried everything under the sun and nothing is doing any good whatsoever. Please give me the benefit of the doubt.

I have 2 configurations of Apache, one that's working perfectly fine and another that isn't. I want to make the one that isn't working work like the one that is working. The one that isn't working isn't allowing any non-localhost traffic yet came installed with wamp which I'm trying to leverage, and the one that is working is an independent install that I've configured to allow all traffic. Configuring the wamp Apache in a way that seems to me to be exactly the same is still not allowing any non-localhost traffic through

Here is the configuration file from the working Apache server:

http://pastebin.com/dQDVDA53

And here is the non-working configuration from the wamp apache server:

http://pastebin.com/geF0aLRF

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Have you restarted the server after modifying the configuration file?

Comment: I'm not sure if commenting again will bump this thread, but I'm going to do it just in case it does.

Is there anybody else out there who can help?